# add() method keeps writing the same object at all the indices in the ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to fill my list always when my program goes through the for loop; however, the same data is written at all indices.

```
Integer nunAcc = JsonPath.read(obj, "$.['Account List'].length()");         
JsonCharacter jChar = new JsonCharacter();

List<JsonCharacter> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                    
for(int i=0; i < nunAcc; i++) {                       
    jChar.email = JsonPath.read(obj, "$.['Account List'][" + i + "].email");
    jChar.password = JsonPath.read(obj, "$.['Account List'][" + i + "].password");
    jChar.characterName = JsonPath.read(obj, "$.['Account List'][" + i + "].character");
    itemList.add(jChar);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
JsonCharacter jChar = new JsonCharacter();
// ...
for(int i=0; i < nunAcc; i++) {  
  // Update jChar...
  itemList.add(jChar);
}
```

is updating then adding the same instance to the list repeatedly.

Create a new instance of `jChar` on each iteration:

```
for(int i=0; i < nunAcc; i++) {  
  JsonCharacter jChar = new JsonCharacter();
  // Update jChar...
  itemList.add(jChar);
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I thought the ""jChar"" was just reused and couldn't be recreated multiple times (FOR) but it worked! Thank you!